# iPhone iOS4 - how to work with address book and calendar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calendar, ios4, contacts

I need to know how I can access my calendar and contacts from my iPhone from my own App? Is it possible?

I need it because I created a stats App and need to know how many contacts and calenders posts the phone has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extent to which you can integrate with other system data is all quite complete in the documentation, and not difficult to find. The bit you're looking for is here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW39

Answer (score 0):

For the address book, see:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html

I don't know about accessing calendar, though.